# Any clever way of identifying if an user key input is on the left/right side of the keyboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm building a React app where the user is shown 2 numbers on the screen on the left and right side of the screen respectively. The user is then prompted to press a button on the left or right side of the keyboard with which he/she indicates which of the 2 shown numbers is larger.

My issue is that is there a smarter way of determining the side of the key input other than literally just making an `if();` statement listing all the key values that you want to be marked as the "left side" and vice versa?

If it helps to narrow down an answer in this case I'd consider anything left from the vertical line `"7, U, J, N"` to be a left side input and everything right (including said keys) to be the right side inputs.

And I am not allowed to change the way the user can answer in this particular case or I'd have done it by now.

Comment: is z left or right? For me its on the right side ...

Comment: Well for me it's on the left side. I guess I could have clarified I'm using a "nordic keyboard" with the "Ä, Ö, Å" layout. I'm okay with a general answer as well and not a case specific though.

Comment: No, a custom if statement seems to be the only option.

Comment: Too bad, I was hoping there would have been some more elegant way of doing it, but could not find any other way myself either.

Comment: not all keyboards have a querty layout, instead of telling them to press any button, why not give the specific buttons to press

Comment: I tried to elude to this fact on the last phrase of my original post. I would change the way the user can answer if this was a possibility in this project. Unfortunately it is not so I have to follow the guidelines I have been given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only input a computer can get from a keyboard is the the key code - which has no indication of the physical position of the key in the keyboard. Although the alphabet is located almost in the same places across all major keyboard layouts, I have seen exceptions.

So, for your program to do the task approximately, one of the ways I can think of is putting the key codes to an array where the left key codes will be placed below the half of the length and right key codes are placed above the half of the array length.

```
//Mock key codes
var keyPos = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];


function isLeft(keyCode) {

    return keyPos.indexOf(keyCode) + 1 > keyPos.length / 2
}
```

You are going to have to get the concept and adjust the code. You may have odd number of keys.

Also, there are many other ways you can do this with arrays. The key is finding the element index and correlate it to the key position.